# Trigger click on one button after user clicks on another jquery and flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to trigger clicking on a submit button in a modal (which i will eventually hide) after a user clicks next as per the below figure:

[image]

I have tried to implement a jquery solution which I believe should work, but it doesn't, and I can't work out why. The code does not trigger the clicking on the submit button. I know that jquery is working and installed since I was able to use other scripts in my HTML. Any help or pointers on how to achieve the clicking of the submit button after the user clicks on next ("Weiter") would be really helpful. Here is my HTML (using bootstrap 5 for the modal):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal_1_Toggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="Modal_1_ToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h5 class="modal-title" id="Modal_1_ToggleLabel">Stufe 1</h5>
                          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {{ form_1.csrf_token }}
                                <p>
                                    {{ form_1.optimise_option.label(class="form-label") }}
                                    {{ form_1.optimise_option(class="form-select form-select-sm") }}
                                </p>
                                {{ form_1.submit(class="btn btn-primary", id="form_1_submit") }}
                                <p id="test">This is some random text</p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#Modal_2_Toggle" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" id="modal_1_confirm">Weiter</button>
                          <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

And here is my javascript found in my js/scripts.js folder:

```
$('#modal_1_confirm').click(function(){
    $("#form_1_submit").click();
})
```

EDIT

As per an answer I am able to trigger the submit button by modifying the primary button HTML like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#Modal_2_Toggle" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" id="modal_1_confirm" form="form_1">Weiter</button>
```

However, now the issue is that while I can collect the form data on the server side, the modal no longer moves to the next after "weiter" is clicked. This was being done using `data-bs-target="#Modal_2_Toggle" data-bs-toggle="modal"`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is not needed in order to make a button which is outside of a form act as a Submit button for that form.
Use the [form attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-form) on your button element.  `<button type="button" form="#yourFormID"`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just to elaborate, in my case I would add form="#form_1_submit" to my primary button? I am struggling to see how to associate this button to both the form and the submit button in the form. Thanks.

Comment: I should maybe specify that the primary "next" button serves two purposes, it also triggers the next modal in a sequence.

Comment: @ojp OK, so what... leave that JS functionality.

Comment: @ojp in my opinion you're doing it the wrong way around. A FORM submit Success callback should trigger that "next" modal slide. So, actually you want to intercept that AJAX success callback, and only if everything is OK (response 200) than you move to the next stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal_1_Toggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="Modal_1_ToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="Modal_1_ToggleLabel">Stufe 1</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          {{ form_1.csrf_token }}
          <p>
            {{ form_1.optimise_option.label(class="form-label") }}
            {{ form_1.optimise_option(class="form-select form-select-sm") }}
          </p>

          <p id="test">This is some random text</p>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#Modal_2_Toggle" data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal" id="modal_1_confirm">Weiter</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```